# Why is the styling set by javascript not working with Ractive.js?

Tags: javascript, css, html, ractivejs

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/boe2vcj6/), on click of the button the following lines are also getting executed along with other ones:

```
document.getElementById("WeatherData").style.visibility = "block";
weatherDataDiv.style.visibility='block';
```

With no effect.

I have searched a lot but seems like the **syntax is correct**.

How to un-hide the div in RactiveJs.

Other frameworks like jQuery and Angular cannot be used for some business reasons.

Comment: What did you search for when trying to find the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change:

`weatherDataDiv.style.visibility='block';`

to

`weatherDataDiv.style.visibility='visible';`

The value `block` is not a valid value for the `visibility` property. The valid values are: visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit;

Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp